# MySQL: count unique days in period with overlaps and gaps (optimized)

Tags: mysql

How to calculate the number of unique days per month from a table with two date columns, in which the periods can have gaps and overlaps?

I rather not use a calendar table to get the unique days, because it generates a temporary table with thousands of records, and resources are limited.

Example table:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| mygroup | alpha      | omega      |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 | 2017-02-04 | 2017-04-14 |
|       1 | 2017-03-25 | 2017-03-28 |
|       1 | 2017-01-23 | 2017-01-25 |
|       2 | 2017-02-05 | 2017-02-20 |
|       1 | 2017-04-28 | 2017-05-12 |
|   etc.  |    etc.    |    etc.    |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: please provide table example

Comment: added example table

Comment: the answer is unique days for each group? Or for each row?

Comment: I'd need the unique days of each of `mygroup` per month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to do this roughly 10 times faster than a calendar table.

The biggest resource spoiler is the calendar table itself, it is used to filter unique days.
But instead of using a whole table record for that, it can be done using 31 bits in an UINT.

Recepe:

1. Create a calendar table with months only
2. Cut periods in months, and join them with the calendar table
3. Translate periods to bits of UINTs
4. `OR` the UINTs per month for uniqueness
5. Count their bits as unique days per month

Output:

```
+--------------+---------+---------+-------+
| Period       | Group 1 | Group 2 | Total |
+--------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2017 month 5 |      11 |       0 |    11 |
| 2017 month 4 |      15 |       0 |    15 |
| 2017 month 3 |      30 |       0 |    30 |
| 2017 month 2 |      24 |      15 |    39 |
| 2017 month 1 |       2 |       0 |     2 |
+--------------+---------+---------+-------+
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  `tabulate`.`period` AS `Period`,
  SUM(IF(`tabulate`.`mygroup` = 1,            
    `tabulate`.`days`, 0)) AS `Group 1`,
  SUM(IF(`tabulate`.`mygroup` = 2,             
    `tabulate`.`days`, 0)) AS `Group 2`,
  SUM(`tabulate`.`days`) AS `Total`
FROM
  ( SELECT
      `unique`.`period`,
      BIT_COUNT(BIT_OR(CONV(CONCAT(
        REPEAT("1", DAYOFMONTH(`unique`.`omega`) - DAYOFMONTH(`unique`.`alpha`)),
        REPEAT("0", DAYOFMONTH(`unique`.`alpha`) - 1)
      ), 2, 10))) AS `days`,
      `unique`.`mygroup`
    FROM
      ( SELECT
          DATE_FORMAT(`permonth`.`period_alpha`, "%Y month %c") AS `period`,
          GREATEST(`permonth`.`period_alpha`, `permonth`.`example_alpha`) AS `alpha`,
          LEAST(`permonth`.`period_omega`, `permonth`.`example_omega`) AS `omega`,
          `permonth`.`mygroup`
        FROM 
          ( SELECT
              `period`.`alpha` AS `period_alpha`,
              DATE_SUB(`period`.`omega`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS `period_omega`,
              `example`.`mygroup`,
              IFNULL(`example`.`alpha`, `period`.`alpha`) AS `example_alpha`,
              IFNULL(`example`.`omega`, CURDATE()) AS `example_omega`
            FROM
              ( SELECT
                  DATE_ADD(
                    MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1),
                    INTERVAL `season`.`n` + (`month`.`n` << 2) MONTH
                  ) AS `alpha`,
                  DATE_ADD(
                    MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1),
                    INTERVAL 1 + `season`.`n` + (`month`.`n` << 2) MONTH
                  ) AS `omega`
                FROM
                  (           SELECT 0 AS `n`
                    UNION ALL SELECT 1
                    UNION ALL SELECT 2
                  ) AS `month`
                  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `n`
                    UNION ALL SELECT 1
                    UNION ALL SELECT 2
                    UNION ALL SELECT 3  
                  ) AS `season`
              ) AS `period`
              INNER JOIN 
                ( SELECT 1 AS `mygroup`, "2017-02-04" AS `alpha`, "2017-04-14" AS `omega`
                  UNION ALL SELECT 1, "2017-03-25", "2017-03-28"
                  UNION ALL SELECT 1, "2017-01-23", "2017-01-25"
                  UNION ALL SELECT 2, "2017-02-05", "2017-02-20"
                  UNION ALL SELECT 1, "2017-04-28", "2017-05-12"
                ) AS `example` ON (
                  (`example`.`alpha` < `period`.`omega` OR `example`.`alpha` IS NULL)
                  AND IFNULL(`example`.`omega`, CURDATE()) >= `period`.`alpha`
                )
          ) AS `permonth`
      ) AS `unique`
    GROUP BY
      `unique`.`period`,
      `unique`.`mygroup`
  ) AS `tabulate`
GROUP BY `tabulate`.`period`
ORDER BY `tabulate`.`period` DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you need?

```
select count(distinct selected_date),te.mygroup, MONTHNAME(selected_date)from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
 cross join test te  
where selected_date between te.alpha and te.omega
group by mygroup, MONTHNAME(selected_date)
```

Оutput for your example:

```
'17','1','April'
'25','1','February'
'3','1','January'
'31','1','March'
'12','1','May'
'16','2','February'
```

Count may be greater than number of the days in month because such overlap exists in few rows - it's not а mistake.

Comment: Nice approach, it seems to work, except for the first output line which has a typo, number of days should be 12. But it is also slow because of the temporary calendar table used.

Comment: No. Number of days should be 17 coz we have April in two rows =) Regarding performance : would be nice to create materialized view instead of using temp table. But as far as I know - mysql not supports it.